# How to declare arrays properly in google protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

Here is how I have defined a message:

```
message PhoneNumberAndTypes {
  repeated Type types = 1;
  Phone number = 2;
}
```

And when I added the types using `.addTypes()` and printed the object in console, it came out like below:

```
phone_numbers {
  types: HOME
  types: MOBILE
  phone_number {
    number: "9912300000"
  }
}
```

But I hoped for the `types` to be like `[HOME,MOBILE]`.

What change should I make?

Comment: "and printed the object in console," - this seems like simply how the console print is working; and how *that* works is implementation specific - yet you haven't told us what implementation (library, framework, language, etc) you are using

Comment: I agree. I think its just the printing part. Actually its a List inside while I debugged it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its a List inside while I debugged it. The "printing" on console did not necessarily reflect the actual object properties.

```
[HOME, MOBILE]
```